# Provisioning profile issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator, provisioning

What I'm trying to do is use my own Iphone and Ipad as a simulator through xcode.  I'm doing this because the built in simulator cannot get past the log in page on my app, any valid user name and password will result in the error message "Service Error, A server with the specified host name could not be found".  Because of this error, I cannot test the code I've changed.

I believe I have the profiles and certificates set up correctly on xcode, when I look at my phone's provisioning profiles in the organizer I see "Ad Hoc, Dist, Dev, and iOS Team Provisioning profile" all with a "Valid profile" status..

But when I try to run the app on my phone I get the "Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'random letters and numbers" cant be found..  I've searched this issue and came to the conclusion that I needed to modify my .xcodeproj project folder, specifically the project.pbxproj file.  I go to that file and delete the line "provisioning_profile[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "random numbers and letters"..

Now when I run the app on my iphone after deleting that line it gives me the error "libxml/tree.h" file not found... I've found the fix to this problem, but once I fix it ill get the error "openssl/ssl.h not found"..

It seems like there is another underlying cause to these problems, because once I fix something it will just break something else.  Thanks for reading and hopefully there is someone out there who had this problem and fixed it.

XCode: 4.6.3
Please let me know if there are any other specs needed that would help in debugging this problem.

Comment: When I've had Provisioning Profile issues like you are describing I deleted any line with `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` similar to what you did  but `PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "id"` would be deleted as well. Then I would restart XCode.

Comment: Thanks for the comment zLAn, unfortentely I went through and tried this with no luck:

It got rid of the (Code Sign error: Provisioning profile "id") error but now its back to telling me "libxml/tree.h" file not found

Answer (score 0):

Often when I've run into this it is because XCode is holding on to old profiles in memory... have you tried restarting XCode since adding your profiles? Seemingly dumb question but hey, I have to ask.

Also when you're selecting your profiles from Build Settings are choosing one of the valid profiles from the top/middle of the list or from the very bottom? The ones on the bottom may be invalid even though they give you a checkmark.